# From Propositional Calculus Proof to Predicate Calculus Proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

PROVE: If {$\Delta_{i}$} are all deductively closed set of formulae, so is $\cap \Delta_i$. Show with predicate Calculus.

Definition: {$\Delta_{i}$} a set $\Delta$  of formulae is deductively closed iff $\Delta \vdash \sigma$ implies that $\sigma \in \Delta$ .

My Progress: In Propositional Calculus I think the proof would be:
let {${\Delta_{i}}$} each be deductively closed. Let $\Delta = \cap \Delta_i $ and let $\Delta \vdash \sigma$ . There is a derivation D = x1, ... xn of $\sigma$ from $\Delta$. Since all assumptions are from $\Delta$ and $\Delta$ is a subset of {$\Delta_{i}$} for all i, all assumptions are from {$\Delta_{i}$} for any i. thus $\sigma \in \Delta = \cap \Delta_i$

I just don't understand how to demonstrate this through predicate calculus instead. There are a few other similar proofs I am assigned where I understand the propositional calculus approach but don't know how that translates to predicate calculus.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: In your propositional calculus proof, I'd be more explicit on when you are using the fact that $\Delta_i$ is deductively closed. I'd expect to see $\Delta_i \vdash \sigma$ and $\sigma \in \Delta_i$ somewhere. I would also expect the same proof to hold for predicate calculus as well, replacing propositional $\vdash$ with the predicate counterpart.

Comment: Oh so is the difference between predicate and propositional largely syntax based and not context?

Comment: Well, yes. Predicate also allows quantifiers (and predicates), but some main features of the deductive system should be shared with the propositional calculus.

Comment: That clears a lot up. Thank you so much!